# Query returned successfully when obvious error should occur

Tags: pgadmin

I have just installed postgresql and pgadmin on my Windows machine.
The problem is that whatever I enter in query window, it results with message:

> Query returned successfully in XX msec.

Even, when query is obviously incorrect, and should cause an error, no error message is displayed - like on screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this ticket](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/2478), the workaround is to set English language for messages in `postgresql.conf`, e.g.

```
lc_messages = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
```

See also [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195177/pgadmin-4-ver-1-5-no-error-messages).

Comment: This site requires an account to be created in order to view the content so it would be very helpful if the information could also be provided in this answer as well.